# Iphone simulator screen rotation

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ios-simulator

How can I rotate the iPhone simulator to landscape?  I have read many items of information, and none of them has helped me yet.  I am using xcode 4, and am developing an iphone application.  Thanks!

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Option 1: Use the left/right arrow keys while holding down command.

Option 2: Under the Hardware tab at the top, select "Rotate Left" or "Rotate Right".

Comment: At the top was missing in every other answer for option 2. thanks !

Comment: This is not working anymore on macOS 10.14.6 with Xcode 10.3

Comment: If keyboard shortcuts aren't working for you, ensure that double check that Simulator > Hardware > Keyboard > Send Keyboard Shortcuts to Device is unchecked. I mistakenly thought that these shortcuts had been removed but this setting disables them.

Comment: If you are using Windows (xamarin) then use Alt+Left/Right keys to rotate the simulator on Windows.

Comment: It won't work if your have both of these options turned on: 
Simulator > Hardware > Keyboard > Send Keyboard Shortcuts to Device
Simulator > Hardware > Keyboard > Connect Hardware Keyboard

Turn one or both off and it should start working. Additional info on what @Uze said. :)

Comment: is there any feature to flip screen on iphone?

Answer (score 5):

For windows keyboard users, windows key + right/left arrow

Answer (score 1):

Just press

```
Command + Arrow
```

key to rotate screen.

Comment: Be specific about the usage of arrow

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate the screen with alt + cmd and the mouse

Comment: This just creates a gray circle following the mouse for me. It doesn't rotate the screen.

Answer (score 0):

just click on the opened simulator and do:

```
command + right arrow
```

from keyboard.